# Output left or right part of a matched string

Tags: r, perl

I have two files, file1 contains substrings of file2. I want to match file1 to file2 and output the part that is to the left of the match and not the match itself. I would also like to know how to output what is to the right of the match and not the match itself. 
Here is part of my data (these strings do probably not match, just example data:

file1

```
 ACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGC
 CUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCU
 UGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAU
 CGAAUCAUUAUUUGCUGCUCUA
 AUCACAUUGCCAGGGAUUACC
 UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGC
```

file2

```
 CCAGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUUUGAGGGUCUAUGAUACCACCCGGUACAGGAGAUAACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGCCAGG
 CUGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUUGGUCGGGUUGUGACAUUGCCCGCUGUGGAGAUAACUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCUAG
 GCUUGGGACACAUACUUCUUUAUAUGCCCAUAUGAACCUGCUAAGCUAUGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAUUUCAGGC
 CUGUAGCAGCACAUCAUGGUUUACAUACUACAGUCAAGAUGCGAAUCAUUAUUUGCUGCUCUAG
 GGCUGCUUGGGUUCCUGGCAUGCUGAUUUGUGACUUGAGAUUAAAAUCACAUUGCCAGGGAUUACCACGCAACC
```

example:

file1:

```
                                                  GCUGUGGAGAUAACUGCGC
```

file2

```
  CUGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUUGGUCGGGUUGUGACAUUGCCCGCUGUGGAGAUAACUGCGCAAGC
```

output

```
  CUGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUUGGUCGGGUUGUGACAUUGCCC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple ways to only keep the text that comes before your pattern, if it exists

```
a <- "GCUGUGGAGAUAACUGCGC"
b <- "CUGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUUGGUCGGGUUGUGACAUUGCCCGCUGUGGAGAUAACUGCGCAAGC"

strsplit(b, a)[[1]][1]
sub(paste0(a, ".*$"), "", b)
```

Now, you just need to read the files into R and loop over each pattern.  I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for, but here is an idea

```
# read data into 2 variables, a and b
# you could use readLines() to do read from disk
a <- readLines(textConnection("ACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGC
CUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCU
UGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAU
CGAAUCAUUAUUUGCUGCUCUA
AUCACAUUGCCAGGGAUUACC
UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGC"))

b <- readLines(textConnection("CCAGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUUUGAGGGUCUAUGAUACCACCCGGUACAGGAGAUAACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGCCAGG
CUGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUUGGUCGGGUUGUGACAUUGCCCGCUGUGGAGAUAACUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCUAG
GCUUGGGACACAUACUUCUUUAUAUGCCCAUAUGAACCUGCUAAGCUAUGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAUUUCAGGC
CUGUAGCAGCACAUCAUGGUUUACAUACUACAGUCAAGAUGCGAAUCAUUAUUUGCUGCUCUAG
GGCUGCUUGGGUUCCUGGCAUGCUGAUUUGUGACUUGAGAUUAAAAUCACAUUGCCAGGGAUUACCACGCAACC"))
```

Now, loop over each value from the first file

```
lapply(a, function(x) sapply(strsplit(b, x), "[", 1))
```

Comment: @ GracieD:Each elements of output are identical. Try:  ll = lapply(a, function(i) sapply(strsplit(b, a[i]), "[[", 1)); for(i in 2:length(ll)) print(identical(ll[[i]], ll[[i-1]]))

Answer (score 1):

Opening file handles to strings for testing:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh1, '<', \ "ACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGC\nCUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCU\nUGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAU\nCGAAUCAUUAUUUGCUGCUCUA\nAUCACAUUGCCAGGGAUUACC\nUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGC\n";
open my $fh2, '<', \ "CCAGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUUUGAGGGUCUAUGAUACCACCCGGUACAGGAGAUAACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGCCAGG\nCUGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUUGGUCGGGUUGUGACAUUGCCCGCUGUGGAGAUAACUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCUAG\nGCUUGGGACACAUACUUCUUUAUAUGCCCAUAUGAACCUGCUAAGCUAUGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAUUUCAGGC\nCUGUAGCAGCACAUCAUGGUUUACAUACUACAGUCAAGAUGCGAAUCAUUAUUUGCUGCUCUAG\nGGCUGCUUGGGUUCCUGGCAUGCUGAUUUGUGACUUGAGAUUAAAAUCACAUUGCCAGGGAUUACCACGCAACC\n";

while ( !eof $fh1 && !eof $fh2 ) {
    chomp( my $line1 = <$fh1> );
    chomp( my $line2 = <$fh2> );

    print join( ' ', split /$line1/, $line2, 2 ), "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
GUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUUUGAGGGUCUAUGAUACCACCCGGUACAGGAGAUA CAGG
CUGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUUGGUCGGGUUGUGACAUUGCCCGCUGUGGAGAUAA AG
GCUUGGGACACAUACUUCUUUAUAUGCCCAUAUGAACCUGCUAAGCUA UUCAGGC
CUGUAGCAGCACAUCAUGGUUUACAUACUACAGUCAAGAUG G
GGCUGCUUGGGUUCCUGGCAUGCUGAUUUGUGACUUGAGAUUAAA ACGCAACC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even try this below Perl code for before , after and match of a string using $PREMATCH($`), $POSTMATCH($') and $MATCH($&)  :

**InputFiles:**

**file1.txt:**

```
ACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGC
CUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCU
UGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAU
CGAAUCAUUAUUUGCUGCUCUA
AUCACAUUGCCAGGGAUUACC
UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGC
```

**file2.txt:**

```
CCAGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUUUGAGGGUCUAUGAUACCACCCGGUACAGGAGAUAACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGCCAGG
CUGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUUGGUCGGGUUGUGACAUUGCCCGCUGUGGAGAUAACUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCUAG
GCUUGGGACACAUACUUCUUUAUAUGCCCAUAUGAACCUGCUAAGCUAUGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAUUUCAGGC
CUGUAGCAGCACAUCAUGGUUUACAUACUACAGUCAAGAUGCGAAUCAUUAUUUGCUGCUCUAG
GGCUGCUUGGGUUCCUGGCAUGCUGAUUUGUGACUUGAGAUUAAAAUCACAUUGCCAGGGAUUACCACGCAACC
```

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh1, '<', "file1.txt" or die "Couldnt open the file file1.txt : $!";
open my $fh2, '<', "file2.txt" or die "Couldnt open the file file2.txt : $!";

while(!eof $fh1 && !eof $fh2)
 {
    chomp( my $line1 = <$fh1> );
    chomp( my $line2 = <$fh2> );

    if($line2 =~ /$line1/isg)
     {
          print "Prematch: $`\n";         
          print "Postmatch: $'\t";
          }
     }     
close($fh1);
close($fh2);
```

**Output:**

```
Prematch: CCAGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUUUGAGGGUCUAUGAUACCACCCGGUACAGGAGAUA    Postmatch: CAGG
Prematch: CUGGCUGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUUGGUCGGGUUGUGACAUUGCCCGCUGUGGAGAUAA Postmatch: AG
Prematch: GCUUGGGACACAUACUUCUUUAUAUGCCCAUAUGAACCUGCUAAGCUA  Postmatch: UUCAGGC
Prematch: CUGUAGCAGCACAUCAUGGUUUACAUACUACAGUCAAGAUG Postmatch: G
Prematch: GGCUGCUUGGGUUCCUGGCAUGCUGAUUUGUGACUUGAGAUUAAA Postmatch: ACGCAACC
```